Correct resets in data that is meant to be strictly increasing over time in Python
I am analyzing hour meter data from a set of machines. When the machine is on, the hour meter increases, otherwise it remains the same. For all machines, I should expect to see only increasing hour meter data. However, there are instances where a software update (or other cause out of my control) will reset the hour meter at any given time and recommence reporting the hour meter data from 0 (Note that based on what I've seen, it resets to 0 and not some other number).
I have the data in a pandas dataframe. The key columns are "Serial" (machine serial) and "Hours". I've written some functions which check value after value, but this takes too long (I have 8 million rows and 3000 unique machines).
I'd like to create a function that corrects the Hours data by adjusting the offsets caused by the "resets".
Here is the code to recreate a sample dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Serial'] = (pd.Series(['Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1', 'Unit1',
                           'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', 'Unit2', ]).astype('category'))

df['Hours'] = pd.Series([3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]).astype('int16')

df['Diff'] = df.groupby(['Serial'], observed=True)['Hours'].diff().fillna(0)

After a few iterations I've landed on this function as a means of fixing the offsets:
def align_resets(group, hours_col, diff_col):
    hours = group[hours_col]
    diff = group[diff_col]
    
    group_starts = diff[diff < 0].index
    groups = np.split(hours, group_starts)
    n_groups = len(groups)
    
    if n_groups == 1:
        return hours
        
    else:
        reset_series = groups[0]
        
        for i in range(1, n_groups):
            last_entry = reset_series.iloc[-1]
            adjusted_group = last_entry + groups[i]
            reset_series = pd.concat([reset_series, adjusted_group]).reset_index(drop=True)
            
        return reset_series

I use groupby and apply to return a "Corrected" column in my dataframe like this:
df['Corrected'] = df.groupby('Serial', observed=True).apply(lambda group: align_resets(group, 'Hours', 'Diff')).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

The code seems to work. It uses np.split to find the index numbers where a negative change in hours occurs, then recalculates what "Hours" should be.
I haven't tried this on my actual dataset, but I wanted to see if there might be a more elegant solution to the problem.

In my opinion, there needs to be clear logic to know that the machine has been reset. In 3->4->6->2,  6 -> 2 has clearly reset, but we have no reason to believe that 3 -> 4 hasn't reset either.

@PandaKim agreed. However the reporting frequency is such that that there would be a value close to 0 after the rest, as the data is reported every fifteen minutes in real time.

Here's one approach:
df['Corrected'] = (
    df.groupby('Serial', observed=True)['Hours']
    .apply(lambda x: x.diff().where(x.diff().ge(0), x).cumsum())
    .droplevel(0)
    .astype(int)
)

Output:
   Serial  Hours  Corrected
0   Unit1      3          3
1   Unit1      4          4
2   Unit1      6          6
3   Unit1      2          8
4   Unit1      4         10
5   Unit1      6         12
6   Unit1      1         13
7   Unit1      2         14
8   Unit1      3         15
9   Unit1      4         16
10  Unit1      1         17
11  Unit1      2         18
12  Unit2      5          5
13  Unit2      6          6
14  Unit2      7          7
15  Unit2      8          8
16  Unit2      9          9
17  Unit2     10         10
18  Unit2     11         11
19  Unit2     12         12
20  Unit2     13         13
21  Unit2     14         14

Explanation

We use df.groupby, select "Hours" and inside apply, we first get .diff.
We chain Series.where and keep the values if >= 0 (with Series.ge), else we take the value from "Hours" (these will be the initial value per group (a NaN) and otherwise all reset values).
Now, Series.cumsum gets us the corrected values.
Finally, we apply Series.droplevel to the groupby result to get rid of the added index level, and add the series as a new column, "Corrected". Optionally, change floats to integers with Series.astype.

Intermediate (before applying cumsum)
(
    df.groupby('Serial', observed=True)['Hours']
    .apply(lambda x: x.diff().where(x.diff().ge(0), x))
)

Serial    
Unit1   0     3.0 # NaN becomes 3 from "Hours"
        1     1.0
        2     2.0
        3     2.0 # -4 becomes 2 from "Hours"
        4     2.0
        5     2.0
        6     1.0 # -5 becomes 1 from "Hours"
        7     1.0
        8     1.0
        9     1.0
        10    1.0 # -3 becomes 1 from "Hours"
        11    1.0
Unit2   12    5.0 # NaN becomes 5 from "Hours"
        13    1.0
        14    1.0
        15    1.0
        16    1.0
        17    1.0
        18    1.0
        19    1.0
        20    1.0
        21    1.0
Name: Hours, dtype: float32


Thank you for your suggestion @ouroboros1 - it worked great! Only took 2 seconds on my large dataset. I really appreciate the explanation as well.

So this does work very good but I did find one scenario where the Hours values for a specific Serial went like [113, 113, 112.9, 112.9, 113, ...] and the Corrected output was [113, 113, 225.9, 225.9, 226,...]. In this case the hour meter wasn't reset - there just seems to be some tolerance in the output I suppose. Need to think about how to handle this scenerio.
